# How Can I set Action bar button icon by Java code

Tags: java, android

I have set the action bar button using xml, but I want to set the icon using java code because I want the icon to be changeable.

I want to set the icon in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first get the item using `Menu.findItem()`, then call `MenuItem.setIcon()` to set the icon

code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.messages).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_email);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: it worked. but the code should be setIcon(R.drawable.iconid);

Answer (score 0):

Get your menu item by index and set icon:

```
menu.getItem(index).setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```

for ex:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    menu.getItem(index).setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you mean like this??
menu.getItem(R.id.messages).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_email);

but it is not working. it became force closed.

Comment: Not item id u need to ue index of the item. Or try find function.